# Tick label is missing

Tags: graphics, ticks

These plots do not show the first tick label on the left:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-.41, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-.42, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-.43, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-.44, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-.51, 1.05}, None}]
```

[image: screenshot]

But these work fine:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-1.41, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-1.42, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-1.43, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-1.44, 1.05}, None}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-1.51, 1.05}, None}]
```

[image]

Am I missing something, or possibly a bug?

Comment: _Mathematica_ will suppress tick labels that would obscure an axis line if drawn. In such cases you will see the tick but not the label.

Comment: @m_goldberg Is it possible to switch off suppression of such tick labels?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is because for Ticks close the origin and with the current image size, the ticks place extend into the positive side of the axes.

Check this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, "Z = " <> ToString@#} & /@ {-.51, 1.05}, None}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: @m_goldberg yes that is what I meant but may be I did not express it clearly. Thanks