# Missing Ticks and Failed legending on LisPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, ticks

Here's mine:

```
plot = Show[
  ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {10, 0.0400}, {15, 0.0740}, {20, 
     0.129}, {25, 0.208}, {30, 0.289}}, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
   Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.02], Black]}, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black], 
  ListPlot[{{0, 0.0361}, {5, 0}, {10, 0}, {15, 0.0155}, {20, 
     0.0545}, {25, 0.104}, {30, 0.163}}, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
   Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.02], Red]}, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
  , ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {5, 0.0646}, {10, 0.0956}, {15, 0.0942}, {20, 
     0.0661}, {25, 0.0393}, {30, 0}}, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
   Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.02], Purple]}, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Purple]
  , ListPlot[{{0, 0.0797}, {5, 0}, {10, 0.0434}, {15, 0.0497}, {20, 
     0.0322}, {25, 0.0227}, {30, 0}}, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
   Mesh -> Full
   , MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.02], Blue]}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue]
  , ListPlot[{{0, 0.162}, {5, 0.0783}, {10, 0.0166}, {15, 0}, {20, 
     0.00804}, {25, 0.00256}, {30, 0}}, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
   Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[.02], Green]}, 
   Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Green]
  , Frame -> False, 
  Ticks -> {{{0, "1971"}, {5, "1980"}, {10, "1990"}, {15, 
      "1995"}, {20, "2000"}, {25, "2010"}, {30, "2020"}}, {0.05, 
     0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, .3}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"Model A", "Model B", "Model C", "Model D", 
      "Model E"}, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
     LegendMarkers -> True], {5, 0.25}]
  ]
```

Two problems are: First, my Ticks label is missing (only on $x=0$) tried to rescale as suggested on [tick-label-is-missing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81101/tick-label-is-missing) but didn't work. Second, i was fail to make a legend. The legend should have a frame and each legend has a mark i.e. a circle mark just like each of the graph.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
opts = Sequence[InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> Full, 
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[.02], Joined -> True];
```

(1) Add the legend using `Legended`, (2) use the options `AxesOrigin` in `Show` and  make the `PlotRange` larger:

```
Legended[Show[
  ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {10, 0.0400}, {15, 0.0740}, {20, 0.129},
       {25, 0.208}, {30, 0.289}},
   Evaluate @ opts, PlotStyle -> Black], 
  ListPlot[{{0, 0.0361}, {5, 0}, {10, 0}, {15, 0.0155}, {20, 0.0545},
       {25, 0.104}, {30, 0.163}},
   Evaluate @ opts, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {5, 0.0646}, {10, 0.0956}, {15, 0.0942}, {20, 0.0661},
       {25, 0.0393}, {30, 0}},
   Evaluate @ opts, PlotStyle -> Purple], 
  ListPlot[{{0, 0.0797}, {5, 0}, {10, 0.0434}, {15, 0.0497}, {20, 0.0322}, 
       {25, 0.0227}, {30, 0}},
   Evaluate @ opts, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  ListPlot[{{0, 0.162}, {5, 0.0783}, {10, 0.0166}, {15, 0}, {20, 0.00804},
       {25, 0.00256}, {30, 0}},
   Evaluate @ opts, PlotStyle -> Green],
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Frame -> False, 
  Ticks -> {{{0, "1971"}, {5, "1980"}, {10, "1990"}, {15, "1995"}, 
            {20, "2000"}, {25, "2010"}, {30, "2020"}},
           {0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30}},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 30}, {-.01, .3}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {-2, -.01}],
 Placed[LineLegend[{Black, Red, Purple, Blue, Green},
   {"Model A", "Model B", "Model C", "Model D", "Model E"},
   LegendFunction -> "Frame",
   LegendMarkers -> "●"],
  {1.1, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly on my output (Thank you so much), but since i need an HD eps file, and use these commands: `exportDPI = 2000;
Export["graphmodel.eps", myplott, ImageResolution -> exportDPI]`. I got this result (the legend is without frame). https://ibb.co/gP25Fcx. What's the problem?

Comment: @user516076, try the answers in this Q/A: [PlotLegend frame disappears during Export](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167724/125)